# "warning: database file for 'custom' does not exist"

Tags: pacman

I write this in console:

```
sudo pacman -S kate
```

but for any package, I get this error:

```
warning: database file for 'custom' does not exist
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not find database)
```

I have tried

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

but I still get the same error.

Comment: You have an error in your `/etc/pacman.conf` (presumably, you have inadvertently uncommented the custom repo which is intended only as a commented example)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your pacman configuration has an entry for a repository called "custom", but you don't have any database file for it. Since this is usually the name of the commented out example in the example configuration, I'm guessing this was a mistake.

If you don't intend to use this repository, you can remove it from your `/etc/pacman.conf`. It will look something like this:

```
[custom]
Include = ...
```

Otherwise, if you *do* intend to use this repository, you should force a resync of your local repository databases:

```
pacman -Syy
```

Comment: The issue was: `/etc/pacman.conf`. I removed that `[custom]` and the next lines.